# Refactoring two methods into one that have the same fields but different names

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I have two event handlers that have the exact same code, except are handling different events. How can I go about combining these into using the same code without having to repeat myself?

```
static void SharePointEventHandler(object sender, SharePointEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ExceptionType)
    {
        case SharePointEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug:
            CLog(LogType.Debug, e.Message);
            break;

        case SharePointEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Info:
            CLog(LogType.Info, e.Message);
            break;

        case SharePointEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Error:
            CLog(LogType.Error, e.Message, e.Exception);
            break;
    }
}

static void FTPEventHandler(object sender, FTPEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ExceptionType)
    {
        case FTPEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug:
            CLog(LogType.Debug, e.Message);
            break;

        case FTPEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Info:
            CLog(LogType.Info, e.Message);
            break;

        case FTPEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Error:
            CLog(LogType.Error, e.Message, e.Exception);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those custom event Args types? can you change the event signatures?

Comment: As Bradley asks, what is the relationship between `SharePointEventArgs` and `FTPEventArgs`. Is there any relationship at all? The biggest problem here is that the method bodies actually are _not_ identical. Each uses what appears to be an `enum` that is specific to the `EventArgs` sub-class. It would be easier if these values were shared by both somehow (e.g. the `enum` was declared outside of the `EventArgs` sub-classes).

Comment: Without a relationship between the two eventArg types, a straightforward way is to make a third method with the shared logic, and the two existing methods each have a single line that calls it. But that's not the one method solution you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending the current state of the code, there are a variety of ways you could refactor this. I'm assuming that at the moment, the two `EventArgs` subclasses are not related at all. IMHO the best way to do this would be to change that. Specifically, create a base class from which both of the existing subclasses derive:

```
class ExceptionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public enum ExceptionLevel
    {
        Debug,
        Info,
        Error
    }

    public ExceptionLevel ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

class SharePointEventArgs : ExceptionEventArgs { ... }
class FTPEventArgs : ExceptionEventArgs { ... }
```

Then you can use the same event handler for both events:

```
static void SharePointEventHandler(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ExceptionType)
    {
        case ExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Debug:
            CLog(LogType.Debug, e.Message);
            break;

        case ExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Info:
            CLog(LogType.Info, e.Message);
            break;

        case ExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionLevel.Error:
            CLog(LogType.Error, e.Message, e.Exception);
            break;
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the variance support for .NET delegate types. A delegate instance can have as a target any method that receives parameters of the exact type specified for the delegate type, or which parameters which are assignable from those specified for the delegate type.